# How to add the value pairs to excel without including the brackets from a python dictionary?

Tags: python

I want to append the key value pairs in my python dictionary without including the brackets... I'm not really sure how to do that.

I've tried looking at similar questions but it isn't working for me.

```
#this creates a new workbook call difference
file = xlrd.open_workbook('/Users/im/Documents/Exception_Cases/Orders.xls')
wb = xl_copy(file)
Sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('differences')

#this creates header for two columns
Sheet1.write(0,0,"S_Numbers")
Sheet1.write(0,1," Values")

#this would store all the of Key, value pair of my dictionary into their respective SO_Numbers, Booking Values column

print(len(diff_so_keyval))
rowplacement = 1
while rowplacement < len(diff_so_keyval):
    for k, v in diff_so_keyval.items():
        Sheet1.write(rowplacement,0,k)
        Sheet1.write(rowplacement,1,str(v))
        rowplacement = rowplacement + 1

#This is what I have in my diff_so_keyval dictionary 

diff_so_keyval = {104370541:[31203.7]
106813775:[187500.0]
106842625:[60349.8]
106843037:[492410.5]
106918995:[7501.25]
106919025:[427090.0]
106925184:[30676.4]
106941476:[203.58]
106941482:[203.58]
106941514:[407.16]
106962317:[61396.36]}

#this is the output
S_numbers       Values
104370541   [31203.7]
106813775   [187500.0]
106842625   [60349.8]

I want the values without the brackets
```

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like the 'values' in the dictionary are actually single-element lists.

If you simply extract the 0th element out of the list, then that should work for 'removing the brackets':

```
        Sheet1.write(rowplacement, 1, v[0])
```

Comment: what happens if i have multiple-element lists, what should i do ?

Comment: That depends on what you want to with each list element. You could for example iterate over `v` in a `for` loop and print one line per unique value, all sharing the same `k`.